# When $ionicView.enter is really triggered

Tags: ionic-framework

Having this function in a controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
```

seemed to be good. Everytime I open the app in the real device, this functions is actually triggered. But then, after a while I realized that this is not always true.

If I open my app, and then close it. And then some time goes, maybe a few minutes. And I open the app again. Well, then the app doesnt start from scratch. It goes back to latest screen/controller I was. And, worst of all, the $ionicView.enter is NOT fired.
If the app is closed and I open again after a while (maybe 5 minutes) then it starts from beginning (showing splash etc).

So, is there a way to solve this issue? How to make the app react going into $ionicView.enter each time it is opened again? Even if picked up from background?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [resume event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) when the app picked up from background, like below:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
function onResume() {
    setTimeout(function() {
            // TODO: do your thing
    }, 0);
}
```